# How to write a Batch/CMD file to check every 5mins if process stops then execute url?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

So i use PHP to execute FFMPEG for video conversions and to save me manualy executing a URL to trigger the video conversions i figured it could be possible with a batch/cmd script.

the process in question is named **ffmpeg.exe**

And the url i need to execute is the following : **website/index.php?option=com_hwdmediashare&task=maintenance.process&format=raw&token=LOL**

I need to check if ffmpeg.exe is running every 5 minutes if not then execute that url or perhaps i am thinking it may be more simple to launch that url through **php.exe** itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way.

```
:loop
@echo off
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq ffmpeg.exe" | find /i "ffmpeg.exe" >nul && (
echo FFMPEG is running
) || (
echo FFMPEG is not running
C:\php\php.exe -f "C:\public_www\administrator\components\com_hwdmediashare\cli.php" process
)
timeout /t 300 /NOBREAK >NUL
goto loop
pause>nul
```

Hopefully nobody sees any issues with my code ? I think i may have a problem over time the memory usage of cmd.exe will be high if anyone knows how to fix that ?